# Quick simple hack to use i as imaginary number in clojure

Tags: clojure

I only need `i` for use in an algorithm. I feel like importing `clojure.math` is overkill for such a task.

Why?

I have no need for complex results, infact there is no need for a real part with the imaginary part. In my implementation, I only use one value at a time and never combine the two, except for multiplication. The output ends up with no reference to `i`, the imaginary part is only needed to see the changes in sign in the computation.

Simply put, it would be nice if there was a way to define `i` as:

```
(def i (....) )
```

such that `(* i i)` equals `-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `(* i i)` to evaluate to `-1` we'll need to prepare a macro.

```
(ns user)
(defmacro *
  [& args]
  (let [i-count (count (filter #(= % 'i) args))
        error #(throw (Exception. "Illegal number of imaginary units."))
        i-factor (case (mod i-count 4)
                   0 1
                   2 -1
                   (error))]
    `(clojure.core/* ~@(conj (filter #(not= % 'i) args) i-factor))))
```

The macro expands to an ordinary multiplication and it shouldn't interfere with multiplication of real numbers.

```
user=> (macroexpand '(* i i))
(clojure.core/* -1)
user=> (macroexpand '(* i i 5 i 6 i))
(clojure.core/* 1 5 6)
user=> (macroexpand '(* 1.3 3.7))
(clojure.core/* 1 1.3 3.7)
user=> (macroexpand '(* i (+ 2 3) i))
(clojure.core/* -1 (+ 2 3))
```

Is a macro necessary? Without a macro `i`s present in `(* i i`) would get evaluated. Since they weren't defined it would cause a compile-time error. As suggested in the question, we could define `i` as a value which `*` knows how to handle. Despite that being possible, it would still be evaluated at runtime. A clear advantage of a macro is the fact that it's evaluated during compilation and replaced with an ordinary call to `clojure.core/*` as shown in examples above. Simply put, it's fast.

Comment: Is a macro neccessary? Would it not be enough to define just a method instead? (I don't know the advantages of a macro over a method in this situation)

Comment: @Zchpyvr, thanks for the comment. I updated the answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Cute solution, illustrating the power of macros.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this quickly hacked *?

```
(defn hacked-* [& args]
  (let [[i-amount product] 
        ((juxt (comp count filter) 
               (comp #(apply * %) remove)) 
         #{:i} args)]
    (if (and (> i-amount 0) (even? i-amount)) 
      (- product)
      product)))


(hacked-* 1 2 3) => 6
(hacked-* 1 2 3 :i :i) => -6
(hacked-* 1 2 3 :i :i :i) => 6
```

You can lexically rebind * to the hacked version to evaluate complex expressions:

```
(let [* hacked-*]
 (* 1 :i 2 :i 3 :i (* :i :i))) => -6
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my hack that assumes arguments are all imaginary:

```
(defn im* [& i] ((fn [q n] (([* str * str] q) ([1 'i -1 '-i] q) n)) (mod (count i) 4) (reduce * i)))
```

...horrible! but what you ask for isn't really possible without for instance hacking [Numbers.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java) to dispatch to a new subtype of java.lang.Number. Really it would make more sense to use a Java or Clojure complex number library.